# adding Arraylist to cookies in asp.net/c#

Tags: .net, cookies, arraylist

can i add arraylist to cookies ? If yes how can i do it ?

I tried to add it in this manner :

Response.Cookies["UserInfo"]["componentArrayList"] = componentArrayList;

But I'm getting error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ArrayList' to 'string'

Please help me.

Thank you in anticipation

Comment: Is there a reason why you're still using `ArrayList` over `List<T>`?

Comment: this is my first asp.net/c# web application. I'm implementing a shopping cart where a user adds items displayed in the grid view to the shopping cart. I'm adding all the items that user selects to the cookies in this manner. My idea was once the items are added to cookies, there will be a link button which takes the user to viewcart.aspx where user can edit the items which could be removed from these cookies.Can you please suggest standard/improvised way of achieving this functionality ?

Comment: The common choice is keeping that information entirely server-side(for example in the session) and just put the session id in the cookie.

Comment: Hi Would you be kind enough to tell me why do u need to put session id in cookie. Won't the information we put in sessions suffice to implement shopping cart ??

Comment: The session is stored on the server. So you need to associate that information with the user's client. And that happens using a session ID. I think asp.net can do that automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize this ArrayList with DataContractJsonSerializer, and store it as JSON, so later you can deserialize it and recover ArrayList's state. Even in client-side code (JavaScript), for example with $.parseJSON jQuery function.

By the way, it's a very bad idea to store an object in cookies, since data size limitation may vary, but it's lower enough to avoid storing large sets of data.

You should consider using cookies to store identifiers and few limited user-specific client configuration, and use both to query server code for other, more specific data.

Comment: this is my first asp.net/c# web application. I'm implementing a shopping cart where a user adds items displayed in the grid view to the shopping cart. I'm adding all the items that user selects to the cookies in this manner. My idea was once the items are added to cookies, there will be a link button which takes the user to viewcart.aspx where user can edit the items which could be removed from these cookies.Can you please suggest standard/improvised way of achieving this functionality ?

Comment: Yes, you can use an AJAXed approach and whenever user adds something to the cart, you store products to order in server's session, so you avoid an intensive usage of cookies and its limitations so far! :)

Comment: what do u mean by ajaxed approach ? Can you please be more specific ? Thank you in anticipation

Comment: Well, now I've to go for a while, but it means that you can send desired products to the cart from client to server using AJAX, storing that cart in a server session "variable".